# Haskell List Comprehension using different variables

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

Hi I am trying to implement a simple function that does this with list comprehension:

```
duplicate "asdf" = "assdff"

duplicate "123456" = "122344566"
```

and this is what I came up with

```
duplicate xs = 
   [ y | x <- xs
       , i <- [0..]
       , y <- if i `mod` 2 == 0 
              then replicate 2 x 
              else x ]
```

I wanted i to act as a counter to keep track of the position of the list, and x to hold the list.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason yours is not working is that your `else` branch does not produce an list inside your function - you can easily fix the syntax issue like this:

```
duplicate xs = 
   [ y | x <- xs
       , i <- [0..]
       , y <- if i `mod` 2 == 0 
              then replicate 2 x 
              else [x] ]
```

but this would give you nothing but an endless list of the first thing in `xs` (because there are infinite many `i`s)

Now my guess is that you indeed want to replicate every other element 2 times and yes `zip` is a great idea and you are almost there (with your comment):

just make sure that you fix the *syntax*/*type* error there as well:

```
duplicate xs = 
   [ y | (i, x) <- zip [0..] xs
       , y <- if i `mod` 2 == 0 
              then replicate 2 x 
              else [x] ]
```

this will give you:

```
λ> duplicate "Hello" 
"HHellloo"
```

which is hopefully what you are looking for

---

### exercise

You can rewrite this into

```
duplicate = concat . zipWith replicate (cycle [2, 1])
```

try to find out how this works

**Hint:** it's based on the idea of: take 2 of the first, then 1 of the second, then 2 of the third, then 1 of the forth, ... - only *obfuscated* by Haskells higher-order function and operator zoo ;)

Comment: Why not `concat . zipWith replicate (cycle [1,2])`?

Comment: nice too ;) (should have thought things trough)

Comment: @Zeta: shamelessly stole yours - there was an issue with the order anyway (as it seems that the first item should be duplicated)

Comment: I think "Hello" is supposed to become "Heelllo", not "HHellloo" (duplicating positions 0, 2, 4, ..., not 1, 3, 5, ...).

Comment: @chepner the `H` is at position 0 if you zip with `[0...]` - the OP used this (`i <- [0..]`) as well and indeed I had it the other way around first - anyway it does not really matter as you can easily fix it bei either starting with `[1...]` or for the other form by switching `[2,1]` into `[1,2]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use zip to provide items with indexes:

```
Prelude> zip "asdf" [0..]
[('a',0),('s',1),('d',2),('f',3)]
```

Comment: hmm so I tried this:
`duplicate xs = [ y | (x,i) <- zip xs [0..], y <- if i `mod` 2 == 0 then replicate 2 x else x ]` but it seems not to be working..